# MS Graph API select "fields" query parameter not working

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Using Graph API to get a list item I can see a `fields` in the result:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}`
[image]

However when I try to use `fields` in a select it doesn't show:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}?select=id,fields`

[image]

My guess is `fields` is a reserved word e.g. `?expand=fields(...)`

- Someone know of documentation to support this claim?
- Or know how to use `fields` in select query parameter?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint) for sites and lists seems to be maybe a little contradicting here. `Fields` is described as facet here, which should be returned by a normal get request (and is returned as you showed). The thing is the doc also uses `fields` as an example for a reference (which need to be expanded). My guess would be that it's both facet and reference and can probably just be expanded/ not be used in a select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Someone know of documentation to support this claim?
Or know how to use fields in select query parameter?
```

For your first question, I have found the docs now.
For your second question, based on my test, you just need to correct your query string:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com/lists/aa8df67a-e7d7-4d33-a57a-20d8e08bf764/items/1?$expand=fields&$select=id,fields
```

The results will be like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('xxx.sharepoint.com')/lists('aa8df67a-e7d7-4d33-a57a-20d8e08bf764')/items(id,fields)/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "\"c19fc274-2a75-48e9-bef1-e5cada2f0cd7,1\"",
    "id": "1",
    "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('xxx.sharepoint.com')/lists('aa8df67a-e7d7-4d33-a57a-20d8e08bf764')/items('1')/fields/$entity",
    "fields": {
        "@odata.etag": "\"c19fc274-2a75-48e9-bef1-e5cada2f0cd7,1\"",
        "id": "1",
        "ContentType": "Document",
        "Created": "2018-06-04T09:55:06Z"
     }
}
```

Note: Multi level select does not support now,e.g. $select=id,fields.title